# Select2 + vue has compatible problem with ie11

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, jquery-select2

I'm facing `Select2` + `vue` compatible issue `ie11`.

Below the image working in all `browser`
[image]

Below the image not working in `ie11`

[image]

> Html Code

```
<div class="row" id="venueblock">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Venue Name <span style="color:#bebcbc;">(Venue / city / address / venue id)</span></th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(associate, index) in Associates">
                    <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
                    <td>                      
                        <select v-model="associate.VenueId" v-bind:id="'select_'+index" class="jsRemoteSelectBox" style="width:550px;" v-select2>
                            <option v-for="option in Venues" v-bind:value="option.Key">
                                {{ option.Value }}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-transparent btn-xs tooltips" style="padding-top: 15px;" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Remove" v-on:click="remove(index)">
                            <i class="fa fa-times fa fa-white"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
            <a v-on:click="add">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Venue
            </a>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:30px;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-wide btn-primary" v-on:click="save">
                Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Vue + select2 code

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/select2.min.js")
<script>
    Vue.directive('select2', {
        inserted(el) {
            $(el).on('select2:select', () => {
                const event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
                el.dispatchEvent(event);
            });

            $(el).on('select2:unselect', () => {
                const event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true })
                el.dispatchEvent(event)
            })
        },
    });

    var appVenue = new Vue({
        el: '#venueblock',
        data: {
            Associates: [],
            Venues: [],
            ServicepartnerId: @ViewBag.Id
        },
        methods: {
            getAssociateData: function () {
                var self = this;
                axios.get('/AssociateVenue/GetAssociateDatas?id=' + self.ServicepartnerId)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        self.Associates = response.data;
                    });
            },
            remove: function (index) {
                this.Associates.splice(index, 1);
            },
            add: function () {
                this.Associates.push({
                    "VenueId": 0,
                    "ServicePartnerId": this.ServicepartnerId
                });
                this.$nextTick(function () {
                    makeSelectBox(undefined, (this.Associates.length - 1));
                })
            },
            save: function () {
                var self = this;
                axios.post('/AssociateVenue/Save', {
                    Id: 0,
                    ServicepartnerId: @ViewBag.Id,
                    Associates: self.Associates
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response && response.data && response.data.isSuccess) {
                        swal({ title: '', text: 'Save success!' }, function () {
                            self.getAssociateData();
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        swal("Error!" + response.data.Message)
                    }
                });
            },
            bindSelectData: function (associateVenues) {
                for (var iCnt = 0; iCnt < associateVenues.length; iCnt++) {
                    makeSelectBox(associateVenues[iCnt], iCnt);
                }
            }
        },
        mounted: function ()
        {
            var self = this;
            axios.get('/AssociateVenue/GetData?id=' + self.ServicepartnerId)
                .then(function (response) {
                    self.Associates = response.data;
                    self.$nextTick(function () {
                        self.bindSelectData(self.Associates);
                    })                    
            });
        }
    })
    var defaultSelectedData = [];
    var selectId = '';
    function makeSelectBox(associateVenue,index) {
        defaultSelectedData = [];
        if (associateVenue !== undefined) {
            defaultSelectedData.push({
                "id": associateVenue.VenueId,
                "name": associateVenue.VenueName,
                "full_name": associateVenue.VenueName
            });            
        }
        selectId = `#select_${index}`;
        $(`${selectId}`).select2({
            dropdownAutoWidth: true,
            allowClear: true,
            closeOnSelect:true,
            width: '100%',
            placeholder:"Type to search venues",
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("SearchVenue", "AssociateVenue")',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        search: params.term,
                        pageResult:100,
                        page: params.page
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data, params) {
                    params.page = params.page || 1;

                    return {
                        results: data.items,
                        pagination: {
                            more: (params.page * 100) < data.total_count
                        }
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
                return markup;
            },
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            templateResult: formatRepo,
            templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
        });

        if (defaultSelectedData.length > 0) {
            $(`${selectId}`).append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", defaultSelectedData[0].id)
                .text(defaultSelectedData[0].name));
            $(`${selectId}`).val(defaultSelectedData[0].id).trigger('change');
        }

        function formatRepo(repo) {
            if (repo.loading) {
                return repo.text;
            }

            var $container = $(
                "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +                
                "<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>" +
                "<div class='select2-result-repository__title'></div>" +
                "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'></div>" +
                "<div class='select2-result-repository__statistics'>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>"
            );

            $container.find(".select2-result-repository__title").text(repo.full_name);
            $container.find(".select2-result-repository__description").text(repo.description);

            return $container;
        }

        function formatRepoSelection(repo) {
            return repo.full_name || repo.text;
        }
    }
</script>
```